# Why don't people trade significance level for power?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, statistical-power, methodology, philosophical

As a convention, we have a lot of studies whose significance level is $0.05$ and a power of $0.8$. However, it is extremely rare to find a study whose $\alpha = 0.2$ with a power of $0.95$.

From my understanding, after an experiment has been conducted, the significance level doesn't matter at all if the result is non-significant, because in this case, we are considering whether it makes sense to accept the null, and all we care about is the power. Similarly, if the result is significant, then the significance level becomes your evidence, while the power of the test makes absolutely zero difference. (By "doesn't matter", I mean "doesn't for the purpose of this experiment". Both significance level and power should be important for meta-studies, so please report both in your publication!)

If I'm correct, then the null and the alternative are to some extent symmetrical: the null hypothesis doesn't inherently require more protection. If you want to prove the alternative, say "this new drug has an effect on the patients", then use a very small $\alpha$ and moderately high power. On the other hand, when you want to prove the null, for example in a normality test, then you should choose a moderately small $\alpha$ and very high power, so that you can confidentially accept the null.

Why are experiments with moderately small $\alpha$ and very high power so rare?

Comment: Because the cultural convention of $\alpha=0.05$ is strongly established?

Comment: @BenBolker This is the reason I like least, but yeah, you're probably right :(

Comment: related: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0032734

Comment: We see 5% all over, but not for any good reason; in many situations we should certainly consider smaller (and in some cases, larger) significance levels -- and in perhaps many more situations still, reconsider whether a significance test is actually the right tool for the job (it is often not, but if all you have in your toolbox is a hammer...). Fisher generally regarded 5% as essentially the *weakest* evidence he'd even consider paying attention to (*and* he was a stickler for replication of experiments on top of that), but for some reason *that* ended up becoming seen as a standard.

Comment: @Glen_b I thought Neyman and Pearson are the ones that advocate the replication of experiments (otherwise they don't need to care about the long-term error rate). The Fisherian approach is designed for scientific experiments, which are not repeated a lot of time in general. What do you mean by "he was a stickler for replication of experiments"?

Comment: All I can say is if you are able to read some of what Fisher wrote about it, you'll see how important he saw replication as part of the process.  I don't have a reference to hand but most of his papers (and comments on other papers) are publicly available. (His books may well be better sources, if not as readily viewed). As an example of its importance, see [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1560901/) ... which says (first sentence of 4th paragraph "*Three fundamental experimental design principles attributed to Fisher are randomization, replication, and blocking*".

Comment: That paper references Fisher's "Design of Experiments, 6ed". However, that mostly discusses the use of replication by the experimenter (which serves several important purposes); he also saw replication by others as important when trying to arrive at facts in the face of uncertainty as well.

Comment: They do. But $\alpha=0.05$ is already the limit of what you are often willing to accept. You'd rather like to have 0.01 or 0.005 instead. A flare discovery rate of 20% is really high.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse You seem to require a minimal significance level of $0.01$ for the result to be convincing, but from my experience not many people would use tests with a power of over $99\%$ (if they conduct a power analysis at all). I could be wrong, though, as I'm merely an undergraduate who don't read papers for a living :).

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Anyway, the issue is not the absolute value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$; it's about their ratio. I feel like there is a convention to make $\alpha$ smaller than $\beta$. See [this paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.00223/full#h4), which states *if $\beta$ needed to be smaller than $\alpha$, then $H_A$ should be your main hypothesis, instead!*. I suppose this practice doesn't make sense in some cases where you are trying to "prove" the null hypothesis (normality test, ANOVA, etc).

Comment: Because of multiple testing and all the various other biases not accounted for, the false discovery rate tends to be much larger than $\alpha$. At the same time, the cost (and risk) of a false positive tend do be much worse. So at 0.2, in reality over 50% may turn out to be false in a more detailed but costly experiment. False negatives often don't cost much, in particular if you assume someone will independently test the same hypothesis again at a later stage.

Comment: But this can vary. If you want to be "rather safe than sorry", and the cost of a false positive (extra blood test to validate the suspicion) may be much cheaper than a false negative (missed infection, causing serious illness). But these situations tend to be individual cases, not so much studies for papers, so you don't see them that much in journals.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks. I think your comments suffice as a great answer. Please consider compiling them and posting an answer below!

Answer (score 10):

> Why are experiments with moderately small $\alpha$ and very high power so rare?

This is all a bit relative, but one could certainly argue that the significance level $\alpha = 0.05$ is already weak, and already constitutes a sacrifice made for higher power (e.g., relative to the significance level $\alpha = 0.01$ or other lower significance levels).  While opinions on this will differ, my own view is that this is already a very weak significance level, so choosing it at all is already a trade-off to get higher power.

> From my understanding, after an experiment has been conducted, the significance level doesn't matter at all if the result is non-significant, because in this case, we are considering whether it makes sense to accept the null, and all we care about is the power. Similarly, if the result is significant, then the significance level becomes your evidence, while the power of the test makes absolutely zero difference.

I can see why you might think this, but it is not really true.  In classical hypothesis testing there is quite a complex and subtle interaction in these things.  Remember that both the p-value and the power pertain to probabilities that condition on the *true state* of the hypotheses (the p-value conditions on the null, and the power conditions on the alternative).  When you get your result from the data, you make an inference about the hypotheses, but you still don't know their true state.  Thus, it is not really legitimate to say that you can completely ignore the "other half" of the test.  Regardless of whether the result is statistically significant or not, the interpretation of that result is made holistically, with respect to all the properties of the test.

It is also worth noting that, for a fixed model and test, and a fixed sample size, the power function is a function of the chosen significance level.  The chosen significance level determines the rejection region, which directly affects the power of the test.  So again, there is a relationship between these things, and you cannot ignore "one half" of the properties of the test.

Finally, it is also important to note that practitioners conducting a classical statistical tests will often just report the p-value of the test and leave it to the reader to choose their own significance level if a binary decision is required.  (That is my preferred approach unless there is a specific need to make an immediate binary conclusion.)  Modern statistical literature cautions strongly against reducing reported outcomes of hypothesis tests to a binary without also giving the underlying p-value.  So in many practical cases, the significance level is not chosen prior to the analysis, and might not be chosen by the analyst conducting the test at all.

Comment: I would agree that $\alpha$ and $1 - \beta$ are negatively correlated, but by the time you conduct the experiment, its design must have been finalized, so at that point, $\alpha$ and $1 - \beta$ are already fixed parameters of the test. For a non-significant result, I can hardly understand how can you interpret it in terms of "the probability of the result being significant when the null is true". Are you considering the fact that a greater $\alpha$ implies a greater $p$?

Comment: A greater $\alpha$ does not imply a greater $p$.  The latter is a function of the data, and is unaffected by $\alpha$.

Comment: I mean, conditioning on the result being non-significant, we have $p \ge \alpha$, so a greater $\alpha$ eliminates the possibility of a small $p$. This is the only way I can understand why $\alpha$ plays a role in interpreting a non-significant result. Is that what you are thinking about?

Comment: Roughly, but even then, the power function only looks at behaviour conditional on the alternative hypothesis being true.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer.  One interesting perspective can be found [in this blog post](https://www.americanscientist.org/article/do-we-really-need-the-s-word), a short citation:

> ... contends the word [significance] carried much less weight in the
>   late 19th century, when it meant only that the result showed, or
>   signified, something. Then, in the 20th century, significance began to
>   gather the connotation it carries today, of not only signifying
>   something but signifying something of importance. ...

If this is correct then Fisher can have meant with *significant* rather something like *worthy of taking a note* (mental or in lab notebook), worthy for further investigation or replication.

This [psyarxiv paper](https://psyarxiv.com/mky9j/) proposing to reduce standard significance level (in psychology research) from 0.05 to 0.005 is further evidence that many see (rightly ...) that 0.05 is already a rather weak requirement.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/506576/did-the-meaning-of-significant-change-in-the-20th-century

Answer (score 1):

Because type II errors are considered to be less of a problem than type I errors. Type I errors have greater implications for future research. Moreover, most of the time, experiments with high power are much more expensive.

But of course you can also question both the whole NHST framework and the way it is frequently misused by unaware researchers...

Answer (score 1):

In a hypothesis test the null hypothesis and the alternative are not symmetric. Hypothesis test logic is connected to falsification logic. The idea is that one wants to be able to make a strong statement of having "statistically disproved" the null hypothesis in case of a significant result. Surely this requires a small significance level; 0.05 seems rather high in this respect, apart from the fact that in the meantime fishing for significance by running lots of tests and selectively reporting significant ones has made a mockery of the idea to "statistically disprove" a null hypothesis (which is one reason why some people advertise lowering the threshold to 0.005, although this won't stamp out selective reporting).

In fact if you run a test with significance level 0.2 and power 0.95 for a specific alternative, apart from subtleties with composite hypotheses, this means that rejecting the null hypothesis means hardly anything, as this will happen all the time (OK, 1/5 of times), whereas not rejecting is clear evidence against the alternative. Basically you run the test the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

> Why are experiments with moderately small α and very high power so rare?

High power is no problem, but the culprit is with the moderately small $\alpha$.

Experiments with only moderately small $\alpha$ are not precise and are prone to observe apparent effects that are not reality and only arrise due to imprecision and noise.

These imprecise, moderate $\alpha$ experiments are rare because the scientific community wants to read about results that are obtained with precision. To perform experiment with some small $\alpha$ is a scientific standard of performing an experiment that is sufficiently precise.

High power can not cure an experiment that is lacking precision. The high power does not change the uncertainty about the results.

> so that you can confidentially accept the null

This is very similar to a [test of equivalence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test) in which you test the absence of a particular effect.

You do not really 'accept the null' only because you did not measure an effect. But you can reject some sort of the non-null, that the effect size is beyond some level, and accept the alternative that the effect (if it exists) must be small below some level.